# Global variable setting fails in JavaScript validation

Tags: javascript, validation, global-variables

I am getting an error while setting global variable **flag** inside function.

Global variable declaration

```
    var flag = false;
```

Function to validate textbox

```
    //To validate Product Name field
    function Name() {
        var pName = document.getElementById('addPName').value;
        if (pName == "") {
            $('#productNameError').text('Product Name is required');
            flag = false;
        }
        else {
            $('#productNameError').text('');
            flag = true;
        }
    }
```

Function to validate quantity

```
     //To validate Product Quantity Field
     function Quantity() {
        var pQty = document.getElementById('addPQty').value;
        if (pQty != "") {

            var regex = /^[1-9]\d*(((,\d{3}){1})?(\.\d{0,2})?)$/;
            if (regex.test(pQty)) {
                $('#productQtyError').text('');
                flag = true;
            }
            else {
                $('#productQtyError').text('Enter Quantity of the Product');
                flag = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#productQtyError').text('Quantity is required');
            flag = false;
        }
    }
```

//Validation Summary

```
    function validate() {
        if (flag == true) {
            $('#validationSummary').text('');
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $('#validationSummary').text('Please fill out required fields.');
            return false; 
       }
    }
```

I am calling first two functions on onfocusout event of textbox and calling validate() function on button click. The problem which I am facing is: inside the Quantity() flag is not getting set to false. Although the field remains blank,record gets inserted.

Comment: _"I am getting an error"_ .... Are you getting an actual error reported, or not?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Maybe is a Synchronizations problem, you can try using Promises, check this article: [JavaScript Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)

Comment: much as I am a big fan of promises, they're only really useful when the functions you're calling are asynchronous, and these aren't.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting flag=true in validate() then you may be calling Quantity() first ,it will set flag false then Name() which will set flag to true so It bypassed validate() function.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the correct way, you are trying to achive validation. Consider scenario, when user have entered the correct value in first filed, flag will be set to true with the fact that second field is empty amd form will be submitted and hold true vice versa.

If want to achive by this way, keep as many flag variables as the number of fields amd chech all those variable inside validate.

Or, use '.each' to iterate each element and validate it and keep appending validation mesages to dom object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use Global Variables**

You're going to have a bad time if you use global variables, you can use the revealing module pattern to encapsulate some of the messiness

Would suggest something like this :

```
var app = app || {};
app.product =  app.product || {};
app.product.validate = app.product.validate || {};

app.product.validate.isValid = false;

app.product.validate.name = function(){
    var pName = document.getElementById('addPName').value;

    if (pName == "") {
        $('#productNameError').text('Product Name is required');
        app.product.validation.flag = false;
    } else {
        $('#productNameError').text('');
        app.product.validation.flag = true;
    }
}


app.product.validate.quantity = function() {
    var pQty = document.getElementById('addPQty').value;

    if (pQty != "") {

        var regex = /^[1-9]\d*(((,\d{3}){1})?(\.\d{0,2})?)$/;

        if (regex.test(pQty)) {

            $('#productQtyError').text('');
            app.product.validate.flag = true;

        } else {
            $('#productQtyError').text('Enter Quantity of the Product');
            app.product.validate.flag = false;
        }
    } else {
        $('#productQtyError').text('Quantity is required');
        app.product.validate.flag = false;
    }
}
```

**console.log is Your Friend**

Try putting a `console.log` inside some of those methods, what I am guessing your issue is is that something is being called out of the order you expect and setting the flag to a value you aren't expecting.

Can do console.log statement like this `console.log` if you open up your developer console should show you the output from the console